# VS22 Windows Forms using C#- Label values not being updated after new value is assigned

Tags: c#

In VS22, I have created 2 Windows forms. One displays 4 labels for profile details: Username, Password, phone no, email

The other form is opened when user clicks 'edit' button to update profile. The 2nd form gets user input from 4 textboxes for the new values.

I've written the following code, making use of object-instances of the 2 forms to interface between them.

```
namespace Ioop_test_3
{
    public partial class UpdateProfileS1 : Form
    {
        public void receiveData(string a, string b, string c, string d)
        {
            //method to get data from the other form, and assign to labels on this one.
            lblUserName.Text = a;
            lblPassword.Text = b;   
            lblEmail.Text = c;
            lblPhone.Text = d;
            
        }

        public UpdateProfileS1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Creating an instance of the other form, and displaying it when button is clicked.
            UpdateProfileS2 updateScreen= new UpdateProfileS2();
            updateScreen.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void btnBack1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void UpdateProfileS1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Tried refreshing labels when the form is activated i.e in focus
            lblUserName.Refresh();
            lblPassword.Refresh();
            lblPhone.Refresh();
            lblEmail.Refresh();
           
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Ioop_test_3
{
   
    public partial class UpdateProfileS2 : Form
    {
        //Creating instance of Form 1 to access one of its methods here
        public static UpdateProfileS1 access_instance = new UpdateProfileS1();
        public UpdateProfileS2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //declaring 4 empty strings AND THEN assigning the values when 4 Textboxes are updated
        //trying this because directly passing the contents of textboxes into method'receiveData'
        //did not work 
        public static string a = "";
        public static string b = "";
        public static string c = "";
        public static string d = "";

        private void btnSaveProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //method declared in other form to get 4 strings from this one 
            //using the instance created above to call method from other form
            access_instance.receiveData(a, b, c, d);
            
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnCancel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void txtNewName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a = txtNewName.Text;
        }

        private void txtNewPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            b = txtNewPassword.Text;
        }

        private void txtNewPhone_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            c = txtNewPhone.Text;
        }

        private void txtNewMail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            d = txtNewMail.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

The label values in form1 do not update.
I've tried :

1. Refreshing form1 when it is in focus, after form2 exits.
2. Passing the strings from the txtBox directly into the method'RecieveData'
3. Modifying access of the strings to public static
4. Messageboxes placed within the method does execute so the method itself is being called no problem
5. Various other things

Comment: `public static UpdateProfileS1 access_instance = new UpdateProfileS1();` - you never display this form anywhere. I highly suspect that you have another instance of it that you should be accessing instead

Comment: I would recommend to create a class UserProfile with the four properties and pass this data class to UpdateProfileS1 and then within button1_Click [BTW: not a good name] to UpdateProfileS2.

Comment: @UnholySheep - I agree. That line is instantiating a completely new instance of the form in memory. I think if they passed in the parent form in the ShowDialog call (eg. .ShowDialog(this)) they could probably cast the .Parent to UpdateProfileS1 and call receiveData on that instance.

Comment: Just set a breakpoint on the InitializeComponent() call in the constructor.  It should hit only once, very good odds it hits twice in your program.  Debug > Windows > Call Stack takes you to the bug.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! (by the way I have given the button a proper name which doesn't reflect in code for some reason! how often this kinda jank happens is scaring me )